# galleriffic with lots of images (around 100)... is it possible?

Tags: jquery, gallery, image-gallery, photo-gallery

as far as i notice, galleriffic embed images on the page, eventhough it use paging, but it still need to load all of the images.

this become problem when i use it with PHP's require_once. The php memory threshold will make gallerific failed to load when i try to load a lot of images.

any idea how to solve this problem ? or any JSON/XML version of Galleriffic which load images on the fly ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully used Galleriffic with Flickr as the image host, have you considered that?

Comment: No, i have not consider it, i need use my own database to show the gallery